# Update Data on MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mean-stack

can anyone help me. I try to understand why i'm not able to update my database on mongoDb... can anyone tell me whats going wrong on the code?
Thanks in advance guys.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/mongo-exercises', {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true
})
.then(() => console.log('Connected to MongoDb'))
.catch(() => console.log('Connected Fails!!!', err));

const exerciseSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    author: String,
    tags: [String],
    date: Date,
    isPublished: Boolean,
    price: Number
});

const Exercicio = mongoose.model('Course', exerciseSchema);

async function updaterCourse(id) {
  const exercise = await Exercicio.findByIdAndUpdate(id, { 
    $set: { 
      isPublished: true, 
      author: 'ANOTHER' 
    }
  });
  console.log(exercise);
}

updaterCourse("5a68ff090c553064a218a547");
```

Comment: has the record been updated in db or not?

Answer (score 0):

`mongoose.connect` returns a promise.

Perhaps the error is not to wait to the connection succeed before attempting to find and update a document on the database.

With the same way you have wrapped the `findByIdAndUpdate` on the async function `updateCourse`, you can do the same to create the connection.

Something like:

```
const connect = async () => {
  await mongoose.connect(...);
  // declare schema here ...
  const exercise = await Exercicio.findByIdAndUpdate(...);
  console.log(exercise);
}
```

Comment: not working rafael... i dont kwon where is the problem

Comment: You don't need to `await` on `mongoose.connect()` mongoose will execute the queries once the connection to the database has been established

Answer (score 0):

I am not so sure as to what error are you getting but may be just try this code maybe it might solve your issue if nothing or old data is getting printed :

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
 mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/mongo-exercises', {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true
    })
    .then(() => console.log('Connected to MongoDb'))
    .catch(() => console.log('Connected Fails!!!', err));

    const exerciseSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        name: String,
        author: String,
        tags: [String],
        date: Date,
        isPublished: Boolean,
        price: Number
    });

    const Exercicio = mongoose.model('Course', exerciseSchema);

    async function updaterCourse(id) {
      const exercise = await Exercicio.findByIdAndUpdate(id,  {
        $set: { 
          isPublished: true, 
          author: 'ANOTHER' 
        }
       } ,
        {
         new : true 
        }
      );
      console.log(exercise);
    }

    updaterCourse("5a68ff090c553064a218a547");
```

Comment: not working... on the console show the msg NULL and on the data base nothings changes

Comment: If it's logging NULL means it can't find the document to update, I guess you put an incorrect `id`

Comment: But when i return all the objects the same id i looking for it show up

Answer (score 0):

**You can follow below link or code**

> https://www.npmjs.com/package/quick-crud

```
async function updaterCourse(id) {
  const exercise = await Exercicio.findByIdAndUpdate(id, { 
      isPublished: true, 
      author: 'ANOTHER' 
  })
  console.log(exercise)
}

updaterCourse("5a68ff090c553064a218a547");
```

Comment: Shuvro can you helpd with that package? i want to get the intire Object from id... ao i get it?
Let me give a exemple:

function updaterCourse(id) {
  qc.index( {model: Exercicio, where: { _id: id}} ).then((doc) => {
    console.log(doc);
  });
  
}

updaterCourse('5a68fdf95db93f6477053ddd');

TERMINAL:

Connected to MongoDb
{ currentPage: 1, pageCount: 1, resourceCount: 0, data: [] }

Comment: ?! Can u help with that npm?

Comment: please read this document clearly. this package made by me and my team

Comment: Yes i didi@Shuvro, i miss understood the reference but in the end a did it. Btw good shop on this package, its clear

Comment: thank you, please share this package with your friends.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;

async function updaterCourse(id) {
  const exercise = await Exercicio.findByIdAndUpdate({_id: new ObjectID(id)}, { 
    $set: { 
      isPublished: true, 
      author: 'ANOTHER' 
    }
  });
  console.log(exercise);
}
```

I think the issue is that the id is being considered a string when it should be of type ObjectId.

Comment: mongoose will automatically convert it to `ObjectId` for `findByIdAndUpdate `
and it accepts the `_id` directly not an object `{ _id }`

Comment: Error: ObjectID is not defined

Answer (score 0):

i think i already know.... on the schema, i should put _id:, only that way i think mongoose can find trough that property

Comment: mongoose will automatically add _id if you don't explicitly set it in your schema, so you shouldn't have to add it.

Comment: Yes i konw that, but if i put that parametr on schema ai can update by id... i know you'r right, but otherwise i can't get eve the object if e don't put that on schema... i don't know how i can update by id with that